# Link to HTML help page in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've got HTML help pages for my website and I'm trying to figure out how to call it from within my ASP.NET MVC4 application. It is just html pages, but when I create a link to the page I get "The resource cannot be found" 404 error.

This sounds like a stupid question, but how do you call an HTML page from within an ASP.NET MVC application?

Comment: Can you please share the code which you have written for creating the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I just had the URL path wrong. I needed to include "Areas" at the beginning of my path where normally I don't have to for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

You could try putting all of your static content in a specific subdirectory, e.g. "/Static/" and then doing the following at the top of the `RegisterRoutes` method in your Global.asax:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("Static/{*pathInfo}");
```

This will let MVC know that anything within this subdirectory is to be treated as static content and not passed through its routing.

So in your case, you could have something like the following:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("Help/{*pathInfo}");
```

Comment: Just realised that solution will only work for HTML files directly in the root directory as the framework will split on slashes - try my revised solution.